# How to close IEDriverServer.exe in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a program which opens desired URL in IE by using selenium driver. However I want to close the driver exe after URL loading. 
I used `driver.quit();` which results into cleaning exe and closing the browser. However I don't want to close the opened browser 
Is there a way to achieve this without using 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");`?

Answer (score 2):

[Helium](http://heliumhq.com) does this for you automatically - if you haven't called `driver.quit();` when the JVM terminates, Helium leaves the browser window open but cleans up the driver exe.

Here's how the implementation works: The Selenium class `DriverService` manages the driver.exe process. We need to manipulate the fields of the correct `DriverService` instance to shut down the exe. The fields are not accessible by default, so we need to use Java reflection to access them.

First, when starting IE, you need to manually pass in the `DriverService` instance:

```
InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder serviceBuilder = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder().usingAnyFreePort();
InternetExplorerDriverService service = serviceBuilder.build();
WebDriver ie = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);
// Open your URL:
ie.get("http://www.google.com");
```

To kill the driver exe, you first need to obtain the service's `lock` field. It is not public so we need to use reflection to access it:

```
Field lockField = DriverService.class.getDeclaredField("lock");
lockField.setAccessible(true);
ReentrantLock lock = (ReentrantLock) lockField.get(service);
```

The `lock` is used to prevent concurrent access to the driver exe. To safely access the driver exe, we need to wrap the rest of the code in a `try ... finally` block:

```
try {
    lock.lock();
    [...]
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Now for the `[...]`: We need to access the `process` field, again via reflection:

```
Field processField = DriverService.class.getDeclaredField("process");
processField.setAccessible(true);
CommandLine process = (CommandLine) processField.get(service);
```

It may happen that `process` is `null`, in which case we can't do anything:

```
if (process == null)
    return;
```

Otherwise, we call `process.destroy()` - this kills the driver exe process:

```
process.destroy();
```

... and set `process` to `null`:

```
processField.set(service, null);
```

That's it! It's some of the stuff that is going on behind Helium's [`startIE(...)`](http://heliumhq.com/docs/api_documentation#com.heliumhq.API.startIE) command.